# embed javascript game in facebook news feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, interactive

How do I embed an interactive javascript game in facebook news feed?   I want to a javascript game to run in FB news feed so that people could play directly inside the news feed without opening another window.  So far, I have seen only flash could be played within news-feed page.

Comment: Did you ever see a playable game in your feed?

Comment: That would be a huge security flaw if that would be possible...

Comment: I have seen an interactive flash in FB feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible.  Facebook won't allow you to run any scripts within the news feed.